# cut down directory against relative directory from ag results

Tags: vim, ag

If search in a long path directory like `a/long/long/long/path/to/project/` with ag, the results list will contain the long path. Is there a way to get ride of project path in result list?

Example results list of `ag test a/long/long/long/path/to/project/`:

```
a/long/long/long/path/to/project/test.txt: test.....
a/long/long/long/path/to/project/js/test2.js: test: function() {
```

what expected:

```
test.txt: test.....
js/test2.js: test: function() {
```

Why I search with specfied directory path instead of `cd` and search? I do the project wide search in vim with ag this way: find the project path and pass it to vim command which will use `ag` to search with given path.

**Solution**

Ps: I use `Plug 'mhinz/vim-grepper`

```
function! VimGrepperConfig()
    function! s:ag_at_project_root(keyword)
        let root = s:find_root()
        if !empty(root)
            execute 'cd' root
            execute 'GrepperAg' a:keyword
            execute 'cd -'
        else
           execute 'GrepperAg' a:keyword
        endif
    endfunction
    command! -nargs=1 AgAtProjectRoot call s:ag_at_project_root('<args>')
    " ag search
    no <Leader>/ :AgAtProjectRoot 
endfunction
call VimGrepperConfig()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ag` produces its result in the quickfix window, you can do a `:cd {path}` in the quickfix window to update the paths presented. You may have to `:cclose` and `:copen` the qf window to see the simplification operates.

I often do a `cd .` after `:make` when my `&makeprg` contains things like `(cd build/path && make target)`

Comment: but my solution invite a new issue. I switch back to last `pwd` after search, now if I open file from quickfix list, it will create a new file at current `pwd` instead of open the file in project. Ah...